# Material UI Dialogue having table change the tabindex vertically

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a `material UI` dialogue which has a table.

```
<Dialog
      open={open}
      onClose={handleClose}
      maxWidth={'xl'}
      aria-labelledby='scroll-dialog-title'
      aria-describedby='scroll-dialog-description'
      disableBackdropClick
      className={css.root}>
      <IconButton className={css.closeButton} aria-label='close' onClick={handleClose}>
        <CloseIcon />
      </IconButton>
{data?.isdata ? (
 <div className={css.tableWrapper}>
            <Table aria-label='simple table'>
              <TableHead> // Here there is a render for table header</TableHead> <TableBody>
                {rows.map((row, index) => (
                  <TableRow key={index}>
                    {row.data.map((item, index) => (
                      <TableCell></TableCell><InputBase></InputBase></Table></div>) : null }
</Dialog
```

Now,Here I have lets say 5 to 6 input boxes now, I am trying , if user press tab then it should happen vertically and not horizontally.

So, How can I achieve this .

Answer (score 0):

Just use tabindex and calculate it based on the row index of the table, here an example that go through the 1st column when you hit tab (before starting, focus an input in the 1st column)

```js
const domContainer = document.querySelector('#root')

const e = React.createElement;

function Field ({ tabIndex = 0 }) {
  return e( 'input', { tabIndex })
}

function Row ({ tabIndex }) {
  return e('tr', {}, [ e(Field, { tabIndex }), e(Field) ])
}

function Table () {
  const rows = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    rows.push(e(Row, { tabIndex: i + 1 }))
  }

  return e('table', {}, rows)
}

ReactDOM.render(e(Table), domContainer)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```